# How to assign/change values to top N values in dataframe using nlargest?

Tags: python, pandas

So using `.nlargest` I can get top N values from my dataframe.

Now if I run the following code:

```
df.nlargest(25, 'Change')['TopN']='TOP 25'
```

I expect to change all affected values in `TopN` column to become `TOP 25`. But somehow this assignemnt does not work and those rows remain unaffected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really want the TOPN (limited to N values as `nlargest` would do), use the index from `df.nlargest(25, 'Change')`  and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.nlargest(25, 'Change').index, 'TopN'] = 'TOP 25'
```

Note the difference with [the other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647745/16343464) that will give you all matching values:

```
df.loc[df['Change'].isin(df['Change'].nlargest(25)), 'TopN'] = 'TOP 25'
```

Highlighting the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Change': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]})
df.loc[df.nlargest(4, 'Change').index, 'TOP4 (A)'] = 'X'
df.loc[df['Change'].isin(df['Change'].nlargest(4)), 'TOP4 (B)'] = 'X'
```

output:

```
    Change TOP4 (A) TOP4 (B)
0        1      NaN      NaN
1        2      NaN      NaN
2        3      NaN      NaN
3        4        X        X
4        5        X        X
5        1      NaN      NaN
6        2      NaN      NaN
7        3      NaN      NaN
8        4      NaN        X
9        5        X        X
10       1      NaN      NaN
11       2      NaN      NaN
12       3      NaN      NaN
13       4      NaN        X
14       5        X        X
```

Comment: @jezrael not sure, it's different, depends what OP has in mind. Both are valid depending on the goal ;)

Comment: Yeah I think I need explicitly N number of observations, so I think this is better.

Answer (score 2):

one thing to be aware of is that `nlargest` does not return ties by default, as in, on the 25th position if you have 5 rows where `Change` = 25th ranked value, nlargest would only return 25 rows rather than 29 rows unless you specify [the parameter `keep`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) to be `all`

Using this parameter, it would be possible to identify the top 25 as

```py
df.loc[df.nlargest(25, 'Change', 'all').index, 'TopN'] = 'Top 25'
```

Comment: which is more or less [what I already described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647746/16343464) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for compare top25 values by all values of column is:

```
df.loc[df['Change'].isin(df['Change'].nlargest(25)), 'TopN'] = 'TOP 25'
```